# Selection of Risk aversion in portfolio optimization

Tags: equities, portfolio-optimization, risk-management, modern-portfolio-theory

I have a portfolio of equities with a cross-sectional score as expected return (mean=0) and am using mean-variance optimization. However, the question is how one selects the risk aversion parameter. The Grinold-Kahn book says that risk-aversion = sharp/(2* target volatility) and the same in the Barra guidelines.
This is however for a benchmark-aware portfolio with no short-selling constraints. Is there a similar solution to this more constrained setting?